# Circumventing webkit bug on positioning <li> bullet wrong after float element

Tags: css, webkit, css-float, position

There is a [bug in WebKit](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=89829) that causes the browser (Safari, Chrome, ...) to position the bullet or number of the first <LI> in an <OL> or <UL> on the right side if it is preceeded by a floated element. Here's a  simple example of the problem:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body style="width:250px">
    <div style="width: 100%; float: left;">
    List with bullet at the wrong side:
    </div>
    <div>
      <ul>
        <li>bullet ends up here -></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Since it has been reported there is some slight chance that it might be fixed at some point.

In the meanwhile, how can I, by only modifying the styling of the *existing* DIV:s, (i.e. without modifying the structure) circumvent the problem?

Comment: [Cannot reproduce](http://jsbin.com/equpim/1) on Chrome 22.0.1229.2 dev-m

Comment: Sorry, while testing, I accidentally pasted a version that did *not* expose the problem. Corrected now.

Comment: It is not fixed in WebKit-r125261 (latest build at time of writing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `overflow: hidden;` on the element after the floated one or on the list.

http://jsfiddle.net/E3FPS/

Of course this has other side effects that come with hidden overflow, such as that you can't move elements beyond the bounding box or they will cut off.

Comment: What is the difference between that and "clear:left" (<blushing>which actually was suggested in the bug report, </blushing> ;-)

Comment: No reason to blush ;) We're here to learn from each other, no? The `clear: left` will actually clear the float and display the cleared element under the floated element. The `overflow` property just causes the content to wrap to it's bounding box. It is still floating next to the other element though.